# Custom UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

My app having two strings with html code .

while loading html string in to `UIWebView` as a plain text we do as below

```
 [webView loadHTMLString:second baseURL:nil];
```

But now in my webview i want to place

```
     1---->a label
    next---->UITableView
    next--->another label
```

where as i want to assign those html string data as a plain text in `UILabel`.

How can i do this?I don't know how to proceed please help me!

Comment: why you want to place all in uiwebview?You mean just show?

Comment: not only in uiwebview main thing i want to convert html strings and asssign them to uilabel

Answer (score 1):

Create what you want to show in html and use the same method to load

```
[webView loadHTMLString:second baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: from the webview i get html strings only based on one tag am loading uitableview